# TinyMCE image upload base64

Tags: image, tinymce

I was making a TinyMCE with image upload, which worked fine initially. I used the filepicker, which opens and displays the image by base64. When saving the content of the textarea, I just filter the base64 and parse it into an image, which I save on the server. So far: no problem, everything works.

Now when I upload bigger pictures, They won't load completely. They only upload 512, which happens to be the max length of 524288 characters in Chrome. For example: an image of +- 800kB only shows up for 5/8th.

Is there any possibility to extend the max length for the TinyMCE filepath field, where the base64 string / dataurl is written?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you convert images to base64 in a first place? Why not just uploading them to your server using the event `file_picker_callback` and set the good image URL directly?

Comment: refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlxsGdIJ6x8